# Pandas add noise to specific column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is my table below, I want to use pandas to add some noise to `x` column only, my current code does not work.

```
x     y
-------
30    0
1     1
0     1
300   0
....
```

I want only add noise to y==1
`noise = np.random.normal(50, 10, ???)`

result

```
x(float)            y
----------------
30          0
1+noise     1
0+noise     1
300         0
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with count nuber of values by `sum`:

```
m = df.y==1 
df.loc[m, 'x'] += np.random.normal(50, 10, m.sum())
print (df)
            x  y
0   30.000000  0
1   52.623817  1
2   56.042890  1
3  300.000000  0
```

Or generate array same length like length of DataFrame - then use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['x'] = df['x'].mask(df.y==1, np.random.normal(50, 10, len(df)))
#alternative
#df['x'] = np.where(df.y==1, np.random.normal(50, 10, len(df)), df['x'])
print (df)
            x  y
0   30.000000  0
1   37.968245  1
2   46.963821  1
3  300.000000  0
```

Comment: I think your second method does not work, it gives 0 then y==1

Comment: @Yiffany - Just testing all 3 functions and working well for me.